# How to delete blob files within folder an Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob folder in Azure called "870" that has various folders within it (see snapshot below):

Blob Pics:

[image: Blob Pics FYI]

I'm just trying to delete only images, not other folders. but I can't. I have a code but its delete all contents(see snapshot below):

[image: My Code]

I want to delete only images(.svg) in "870" folder, not other folders data as well as folders.

Comment: Please don't post your code as a picture. Use the code snippets so others can recreate your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to delete image files in the 870 folder, you should set the parameter to `false` for `ListBlobs()` method, it works at my side.

```
            foreach (IListBlobItem blob in cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("your folder path").ListBlobs(false))
            {

                if (blob.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    ((CloudBlockBlob)blob).DeleteIfExists();                    
                }
            }
```

And if you set `true` for `ListBlobs()` method, it will also list the files in the sub-folders of 870. And then cause the sub-folders and files within it being deleted(because you can not have a empty folder in the azure blob storage).

You can also refer to this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet#parameters) about parameter `useFlatBlobListing`:

**A boolean value that specifies whether to list blobs in a flat listing, or whether to list blobs hierarchically, by virtual directory.**